# Need to Copy Data with Parent Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with parent child relationship and want to copy the same rows for a different entity in the same table keep the parent child relationship in sync with one another For eg.

table

```
Id ParentId EnityId CreatedTime
1  null     'me202' 20/1/2019 12:00:25
2  1        'me202' 20/1/2019 12:02:25
3  2        'me202' 20/1/2019 12:04:25
4  1        'me202' 20/1/2019 12:06:25
```

i want to copy above records for entity 'me203' such as:

```
Id ParentId EnityId CreatedTime

1  null     'me202' 20/1/2019 12:00:25
2  1        'me202' 20/1/2019 12:02:25
3  2        'me202' 20/1/2019 12:04:25
4  1        'me202' 20/1/2019 12:06:25

5  null     'me203' 20/1/2019 12:00:25
6  5        'me203' 20/1/2019 12:02:25
7  6        'me203' 20/1/2019 12:04:25
8  5        'me203' 20/1/2019 12:06:25
```

i am using the following query :

```
INSERT INTO abc  (ParentId, EnityId)
Select 
Case 
WHEN ParentId IS NULL THEN ParentId 
ELSE

(Select top 1 id From abc Where 
CreatedTime = (Select CreatedTime From abc Where id = ParentId )
AND id != ParentId  AND EnityId = 'me203')
END 
, 'me203'

From abc Where entityid= 'me202'
```

parent is been inserted as null by the above query.

Comment: You would only be able to achieve this with iteration; as a requirement of inserting the child is knowing the value of the ID of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your `id` column is of type `int identity(1,1)`:

```
declare @entityId nvarchar(20) = 'me202'
declare @newEntityId nvarchar(20) = 'me203'
declare @id int;
declare @parentId int;
declare @createdTime datetime;
declare @newParentIdOffset int;

declare myc cursor for
    select  Id,
            ParentId,
            CreatedTime
    from    abc
    where   entityId = @entityId
    order by Id;

open myc;

fetch next from myc into @id, @parentId, @createdTime

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if (@parentId is null)
    begin 
        insert into abc (EntityId, CreatedTime) values (@newEntityId, @createdTime)

        select @newParentIdOffset = (id - @id) from abc where EntityId = @newEntityId
    end else begin
        insert into abc (EntityId, CreatedTime, parentId) values (@newEntityId, @createdTime, @parentId + @newParentIdOffset)
    end

    fetch next from myc into @id, @parentId, @createdTime
END

close myc;

deallocate myc;
```

Comment: This *could* however have concurrency issues, if other users are performing `INSERT` operations against the table. For example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=518d5165963accd6761862e837304fbd)

Answer (score 0):

Wow this is ugly, but it does work...

```
DECLARE @StartID int = 1;

DECLARE @Rows table (ID int, ParentID int, EntityID char(5), CreatedTime datetime2(0), [Level] int);

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.ParentID,
           YT.EntityID,
           YT.CreatedTime,
           1 AS [Level]
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
    WHERE YT.ID = @StartID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.ParentID,
           YT.EntityID,
           YT.CreatedTime,
           r.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN rCTE r ON YT.ParentID = r.ID)
INSERT INTO @Rows (ID,
                   ParentID,
                   EntityID,
                   CreatedTime,
                   Level)

SELECT r.ID,
       r.ParentID,
       'me203' AS EntityID,
       r.CreatedTime,
       r.[Level]
FROM rCTE r
ORDER BY r.ID;

DECLARE @I int = 1;
DECLARE @IDs table (New int, Old int)

WHILE @I <= (SELECT MAX([Level]) FROM @Rows) BEGIN

    MERGE INTO dbo.YourTable YT USING @Rows R ON [Level] != @i
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ParentID,EntityID, CreatedTime)
        VALUES (R.ParentID, R.EntityID, R.CreatedTime)
        OUTPUT inserted.ID, R.ID
        INTO @IDs (New,Old);

    UPDATE R
    SET R.ParentID = I.New
    FROM @Rows R
         JOIN @IDs I ON R.ParentID = I.Old
    WHERE R.[Level] = @I + 1

    SET @I = @I + 1;

END
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=96b436d8bd3a8198a582fbdfd6a95c00)

Comment: It would be great it whomever voted this down could explain why this isn't useful; when the DB Fiddle shows this supplies the results requested.